# How to hide or disable the input field which appears when clicking the axis in plotly.js?

Tags: plotly

How to hide or disable the input field which appears when clicking the axis in plotly.js?

[image: Input field which appears when clicking the axis.]

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to generate the plot? Also indicating which language you are using would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, it's plotly.js, edited the post. I haven't set anything in the layout or configuration which would enable this functionality. Didn't find anything in the reference, also not even sure what is this called.

Comment: You can add your JS code to the question, without people won't be able to help you without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Add this to your CSS:

```
.drag.wdrag.cursor-w-resize {
  display: none;
}
```